# Issues with amdmemtweak: Couldn't open DRI under debugfs : Permission denied Cannot find DRI instance for pci:0000:06:00.0

Tags: gpu-driver, amdgpu

Im trying to use amdmemtweak with ubuntu 22.04 and amdgpu drivers installed from their website.
I need the opencl driver to use with mining.
Im unable to use amdmemtweak.

Couldn't open DRI under debugfs
: Permission denied
Cannot find DRI instance for pci:0000:06:00.0

Comment: What command do you run to get this output?

Comment: miner@8gpu:/miner/build/amdmemorytweak/linux$ ./amdmemtweak --c            Couldn't open DRI under debugfs
: Permission denied
Cannot find DRI instance for pci:0000:06:00.0

Comment: Run it with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

So basically ive had no success trying to make it work. On the project github page many other people saying that it doesn't work anymore because the amdgpu drivers are newer now.

Im testing using a docker container instead.